# Shorting thermal sensor in iMac 2010?

Tags: imac, ssd

I want to install an SSD in an iMac 2010. The thermal sensor has no place to install, and if I don't install it, fans will spin at maximum speed.

I read that I can disable the HDD thermal sensor by simply shorting the pins. Is that true?

edit: I shorted the pin and the iMac works great

Comment: @Allan yes, but a software solution that might break after an update is worse. I'm just scared of shorting stuff, because there are not many people online to write that, so I wonder if it's true or not. If it's some analog value,  maybe shorting it's 0 degrees, but if it's a digital value, shorting won't do good to the system...

Comment: The *highest voted* answer in the linked question is not software and there's an alternate answer to your question as well.

Comment: @Allan my sensor is different than that cable, i have the previous imac. Plus waiting at least 3 weeks (i'm not in the US) to speedup this mac.....

Comment: Shorting it just tricks the SMC into thinking the value is 0 (no resistance).  This obviously bypasses any safeguards.

Comment: The answer was about a 2009 iMac.  2010 is the same "generation"

Comment: yes i saw the link, it applies to my mac also :)